# How to create a prompt in a new tab opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs

**Code:**

```
button = document.getElementById('button');
function buttonPress(){
    input = document.getElementById('input');
    url = input.value;
    console.log(url);
     let a = window.open(url,"name");
     a.focus();
    setTimeout(console.log("wait until confirm"),4000);
    if(confirm('Start download?')){
        alert('Downloading');
    }
    else{
        alert('Why you no love me...');
        window.close;
    }
}
button.addEventListener("click",buttonPress)
```

The problem is that the confirm opens in the previous tab, not in the new one. I've tried with location.replace or href but it still doesn't work. Any ideas how I could get there?

Answer (score 1):

this happens because the code you wrote is running in the previous page.

therefore, any function that you will use will write and call in this javascript snippet will run inside the previous page.

**to solve this problem, you can add the confirm function in the javascript section of the url which you open.**

Comment: Ok, that I can understand. But how can I change it to run in the new URL? That's what I can't get fixed

Comment: When you open a new url, it renders a new html that has nothing common with the other one. If you want to achieve confirmation before download, I can recommend you change the order, and confirm first and only then visit the url.